# Is it ok to say 'the Japanese' referring to Japanese people?

Tags: grammar

Also if the answer is yes, would the corresponding verb be singular or plural?

Comment: Look this up [here](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/Japanese), where AHDEL for instance says that _Japanese_ used as a noun (for a person / people) is spelt the same way in the plural.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Nationalities - When do we use the singular or plural form](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/151556/nationalities-when-do-we-use-the-singular-or-plural-form)

Answer (score 1):

> Yes, [Japanese](http://www.learnersdictionary.com/definition/Japanese) /ˌʤæpəˈniːz/ noun
>
> - the Japanese : the people of Japan : Japanese people

Verb usage example: She **is** Japanese but Japanese people **are**...

> Example of an Adj. use-
>
> - “the Japanese Emperor”, “Japanese cars”